# How can I find the deeplink used by Google Play Store to open installed applications?

Tags: android, google-play, deep-linking

Google Play Store allows us to "open" installed applications. I assume they do this using deep links of the said applications. I want to find out the deeplink they are using to open said application, eg google assistant, google meet. How can I find the deeplinks?

If i can get the deeplink they are using to open google assistant that would be enough. I dont want digital flow I want to use the method play store uses to open other applications.

I cant find out what deeplink they are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Playstore uses deep links but just simple Intents.
You can start another application by providing inside the query tag of your app's Manifest the package id of the app you want to open, e.g. Google Fit:

`<queries> <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.fitness" /> </queries>`

then launch the intent providing the package name you want, e.g.:

```
activity?.packageManager?.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.fitness")
```

You can find app's package name analyzing the app's Manifest.

More details on the official [Android doc's page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending)